# HTML5 Canvas: how to have an image and a shape on the canvas and shape is Drag n Droppable?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm having trouble creating an HTML5 canvas in which a an image is present, a shape is present, and the shape is draggable on the same stage. My gut tells me that I need to create multiple layers or multiple stages/canvases. Then have one be regular and the other be Kinetic. I've found some code for draggable shapes, code for displaying images and shapes, and I think my problem only lies in the implementation of the syntax. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.10.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 578,
          height: 200

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var rectX = stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
        var rectY = stage.getHeight() / 2 - 25;

        var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: rectX,
          y: rectY,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          fill: "#00D2FF",
          stroke: "black",
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true
        });

        var layer1 = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          var image = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 53,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
            image: imageObj,
            width: 106,
            height: 118
          });

          layer1.add(image);
          stage.add(layer1);

        // add cursor styling
        box.on("mouseover", function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        });
        box.on("mouseout", function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        });

        layer.add(box);
        stage.add(layer);

        imageObj.src = "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg";
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is not Java related.

Comment: My fault for adding that tag to it. According to my research HTML5 canvas utilizes Java or Javascript sometimes in the body of the code. I considered perhaps Java users might have a perspective on my question as well. They still might, it's just that you don't.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not related in any way other than having similar names.

Comment: [Java](http://java.com/en/download/faq/whatis_java.xml) is a programming language that runs on a PC. [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) is markup language for web pages development, although you can use Java (or any other language) to handle request to a server. When you create a single page using HTML 5, you don't write Java and it does not use Java behind the scenes. Still, it looks like HTML 5 canvas is similar to Java Graphics: http://canvastoolkit.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website: [w3shools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_draganddrop.asp)